# gdb issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c, gdb, ubuntu-14.04

The system is Ubuntu 14.04 32bit, upgraded to the latest version.

test2.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
void test() {
    sleep(1000);
}
int main() {
    test();
}
```

Compile it:

```
gcc /tmp/test2.c -o /tmp/test2 -g
```

Run and try to attach it with gdb:

```
$ sudo gdb -p 9038
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
...
Attaching to process 9038
Reading symbols from /tmp/test2...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
0xb7799cb0 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7799cb0 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

The gdb could load symbols from binary, but it just cannot parse the stack correctly. It's really weird.

Any suggestion?

Comment: gdb is working fine. It is certainly you making a mistake. Try compiling with `-Og` and do some research about debugging optimised code.

Comment: I don't know who look down my question. I must say that I am not a newbie. In fact, even for optimized program, the gdb should not perform like this. I used gdb for many years, but it's very strange that it does not work on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit, even for the simple case I showed, so I'm asking question to see if somebody happens to have the same issue. If you think I'm using the wrong words, I could change the title. And if you know the answer, please tell me directly. But please do not look down the question in your own taste. Thank you all.

Comment: What happens if you use `up` and `down` commands? What happens if you run the executable directly from gdb as opposed to attaching to the process?

Comment: I can reproduce this problem in gdb 7.7.1. But it works OK in every version from 7.8 onward. Suggest getting the latest source from ftp://sourceware.org/pub/gdb/releases/ and compiling it. You'll need to install the `python-dev` and `libncurses-dev` packages first, using `apt`.

Comment: After some more testing: gdb 7.7.1 works OK on 14.04 (with kernel 3.13), but not on 14.04.3 (with kernel 3.19). Maybe the vsyscall page changed between 3.13 and 3.19 and gdb 7.7.1 didn't completely handle the new format.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, thank you! Your answer is very useful to me. The gdb 7.8 works fine. I also suspect it's related to the kernel version.